# How to convert GIMP gradient to Photoshop compatible Gradient?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, gradient

I want to convert GIMP Gradient to Photoshop compatible gradient (importable)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert GIMP gradients to PaintShop Pro at [cptutils-online](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cptutils-online/select.html), and you should be able to import those into PhotoShop (both are variants of the GRD format, PSP uses version 3, PS uses version 5). If PS does not recognise the files with a `.PspGradient` extension then try renaming them with a `.grd`

Comment: Interesting. It seems based on [cputils](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/jjg/en/code/cptutils.html) open source package.

Comment: Indeed it is, hence the name :-)

Answer (score 1):

The gradient format in photoshop, unlike GIMP's is a proprietary binary format.
There are some tools that can be found to make the conversion - I could find [cptutils](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/jjg/en/code/cptutils.html) - which also features an online version.

Another option, if photoshop has the ability to import gradients from CSS files, GIMP can export its gradients to CSS, by right-clicking on them on the gradients dialog. - But I don't know if photoshop can do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Help. I checked cptutils online conversion option where Gimp gradient can be converted in many other formats except Photoshop gradient. Moreover, there is no option to import gradients from CSS files. Feeling Helpless Anyway Thanks again for the support

Comment: cptutils online does not work, error for every file i import and try to convert. It is useless.